# Could azure data warehouse be inside an Azure SQL Elastic Pool?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse, azure-elasticpool

I am just wondering if there is any possibility to add an Azure data warehouse database into an Azure elastic pool. From my knowledge, an Azure DWH database can have 500 MB in size but an elastic pool has a maximum quota of 250 MB. Is it the reason for which I can't add the DWH in the pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently DWUs are used by SQL Azure Data Warehouse on per Data Warehouse basis. DWUs cannot be assigned to resource pools at this time.

This has been suggested by other Azure customers before as you may see on below URL:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/14204067-implementing-elastic-pools-for-azure-sql-data-ware

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo